# How to print the column names along with the column co-efficients for Logistic Regression in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()

logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)

print(logreg.coef_ )
print(X.columns)
```

How can I zip the logreg.coef_  long with their column names?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
# Create lists
column_labels = X.columns.tolist()
coef = logreg.coef_.squeeze().tolist()

# Zip together
labels_coef = list(zip(column_labels, coef))

# Verify the result
print(labels_coef)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Coefficients and features in zip

```
print(list(zip(X_train.columns.tolist(),logreg.coef_[0])))
```

## Coefficients and features in DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame({"Feature":X_train.columns.tolist(),"Coefficients":logreg.coef_[0]})
```

[image]